# what is the geometical interpretation of $\vec a.\vec b$?

Tags: vector-spaces

what is the geometical interpretation of $\vec a.\vec b$?(dot product)

I know the projection of $\vec a $ on $\vec b$ is $\vec a.\hat b$.

But what is a projection here?

Answer (score 0):

one interpretation of $a \cdot b$, after you scale both of them to be unit vectors, is how well $a$ and $b$ are correlated. they are positively correlated if $a.b = 1$ and negatively correlated if $a.b = -1$ and in between measured by $\cos$ of the angle between them.

Comment: Shouldn't this be $>0$ or $<0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, i am not what you mean? can you give me some hint?